# Как сделать из запроса "живой поиск"?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
function Ajax()
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('send-form'));
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.open("POST", "search.php", true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
</script>

<form id="send-form" method="POST">
<input type="search" name="search">
<input type="submit" onclick="Ajax(); return false;" value="Поиск">
</form>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Данный код отправляет запрос только по нажатию. Каким образом можно сделать "живой поиск"? Без всяких наворотов в лице подсветки и т.д. На нативном JS. Без фреймворков.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `onchange` атрибут, передав в него функцию, которая будет отрабатывать на каждое изменение в инпуте ввода текста (`<input type="search" name="search">`). На практике для такого обработчика пишется отдельная функция, которая будет содержать задержку на случай если юзер печатает быстро, т.к. нет смысла делать запрос каждый раз.
Подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange)

В вашем случае форма будет выглядеть так:

```
<form id="send-form" method="POST">
  <input type="search" onchange="Ajax(); return false;" name="search">
  <input type="submit" onclick="Ajax(); return false;" value="Поиск">
</form>
```

Comment: Получаю такую ошибочку в консоли браузера: Unable to get property 'isPersonal' of undefined or null reference. Причем разово появилась и больше не выходит.

Comment: @Алексей попробуйте отправить в onchange вместо Ajax(); вызов тествой фукнции (function() { console.log('test'); })(), чтобы убедится, что обработчик отрабатывает.